# can we display the total of calculatorform example in a new window? the new window opens with a pushbutton present on main window?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using calculatorform example as my base. I have a pushbutton in the same window that opens to a new window. now i want the sum to be displayed in the new window and not the main window.
Is there anyone who has any idea about how to do this? Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Connect the value changed of the output label to the set text of the label in the new window.  If you haven't already, I suggest you explore [Signals & Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) it explains the concepts quite well. [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QLabel.html) docs would probably be of help too.